# Mac OS can't load Bootstrap CDN on any browser

Tags: macos, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a website that uses bootstrap but whenever I load the website in my user account I get these errors (referring to bootstrap CDN)

**SAFARI**

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection reset by peer
[Error] Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection reset by peer
[Error] Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection reset by peer
```

**CHROME**

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

**FIREFOX**

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css. (Reason: CORS request failed). <unknown>
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css. (Reason: CORS request failed). <unknown>
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js. (Reason: CORS request failed). <unknown>
```

This **only** happens **on my user account** and has been happening for a while, only now have i asked for help!

I also can't load getbootstrap.com the loading bar just hangs. (This also happens on other websites to)

Edit:
This is in my header

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Change your header code to this

I removed the

```
integrity="<string>" crossorigin="anonymous"
```

From the link